# Is there any way to access <ion-app> tag inside a page?

Tags: html, css, ionic3

I am new to ionic. I am using an npm package called "ionic-multi-camera" to capture multiple pictures in a single instance.The app requires the following styling in app.scss

```
    ion-app, ion-content, .nav-decor {
     background-color: transparent !important;
   }
```

But the problem is that this affects the background of the whole app after taking pictures.
[image: changes white background to transparent for the whole app]

I tried conditionally setting the background to transparent of ion-content in a page but it didn't work,i.e,it doesn't show the camera view but only the pictures it has taken. 
[image: no transparent camera]

Is there any way to access ion-app in a page so as to conditionally set background color of the whole app only when the camera is in use?